# Inserting images in a GCE account

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am trying to register/insert an image in a gce account. This raw image source is shared publicly. However, I see this error when making the insert call

```
{u'status': u'DONE', u'kind': u'compute#operation', u'name': u'operation-1413287109771-505608c24bef9-5c02ac49-1dbd219b', u'startTime': u'2014-10-14T04:45:10.142-07:00', u'httpErrorMessage': u'FORBIDDEN', u'insertTime': u'2014-10-14T04:45:09.871-07:00', u'targetLink': u'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/qubole-gce-test/global/images/image-v1-36', u'operationType': u'insert', u'error': {u'errors': [{u'message': u"Required 'read' permission for 'rawDisk.source'", u'code': u'PERMISSIONS_ERROR'}]}, u'progress': 100, u'endTime': u'2014-10-14T04:45:11.625-07:00', u'httpErrorStatusCode': 403, u'id': u'15732625722022858454', u'selfLink': u'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/qubole-gce-test/global/operations/operation-1413287109771-505608c24bef9-5c02ac49-1dbd219b', u'user': u'964307357192-smkpef2g0v8q3oopq44tvh1d3h1lplgk@developer.gserviceaccount.com'}
```

I googled and from the posts I found, it says thay you have to share the image publicly - which I have already done.

I am using this API https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/images/insert

The rawDisk.source that I am using here is the GCS URL which I have made public, yet I am getting the error I pasted.

Answer (score 1):

As [discussed](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/gce-discussion/oQR6yhR9nwE/discussion) on the gce-disussion mailing list this is a known regression in GCE that the engineering team is working on.  As a workaround you can get this API working by adding the GCS read-write scope (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write) to the scopes you request when performing OAuth2 authentication.